# React Native Mobile Application Data Transfer Without Internet

Tags: react-native, p2p

my idiom is to develop a great cafe / restaurant automation with React Native. Even if the internet connection is cut, the communication between the waiter and the kitchen should not be interrupted. How can I exchange data between two devices connected to the same network?
I've tried systems like p2p, but p2p works like client and server. Both devices I need can be both client and server.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. You can use [this npm package](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) which will gives you options to check the status of the connectivity. For instance you can use a server on your local area network where your kitchen and waitress are. Using the the above npm package you can have your application switch backend servers based on connectivity.You can even then make your local backend server sync data to your main cloud server upon restoration of internet connectivity

Comment: Thank you for answer,

Comment: Can a device be both a client and a server? Can I provide this using tcp / udp protocols?

Comment: It depends on what device you are talking about. I don't think it makes sense to make a mobile device a server. So you will need a dedicated desktop server to act as server